# Access a Lambda function inside a private subnet using API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I have a VPC containing 2 Lambda functions A & B:

- A is on 2 public subnets
- B is on 2 private subnets with a RDS Database instance

The VPC itself has Internet access via the NAT instance.
I need a 3rd party API to communicate with B, but B is in a private subnet. Now I was wondering whether API Gateway solves this problem or whether it requires more work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the 3rd-party to **invoke** the Lambda function and pass data to it, then **AWS API Gateway** is correct for the task. That is exactly what API Gateway is designed to do.

See: [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon API Gateway - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html)

Alternatively, you could use an Elastic Load Balancer and have it invoke the Lambda function.

From: [Using AWS Lambda with an Application Load Balancer - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-alb.html)

You also mention that you have an AWS Lambda "on 2 public subnets". **AWS Lambda functions should *not* be configured to connect to public subnets.** They should either be configured to use "No VPC" (in which case they can directly access the Internet), or they should be connected to private subnets (and can use a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance to access the Internet if required).

See: [Configuring a Lambda function to access resources in a VPC - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html):

> Connect your function to **private subnets** to access private resources. If your function needs internet access, use network address translation (NAT). Connecting a function to a public subnet doesn't give it internet access or a public IP address.

Comment: Thanks for your answer John, but could you explain why they shouldn’t be on public ones?

Comment: Added link to, and quote from, documentation.